# Can I get VS Code to run an Android emulator using cmdline-tools in flutter?

Tags: linux, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

### Preface

To preface, I am not willing to download Android Studio on this machine, and hence am looking for solutions that do **not** entail its use, if at all possible. Thank you.

### Context

Running `flutter doctor` provides the following output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Arch Linux 6.4.11-arch2-1, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Note that the `[✓] Connected device (1 available)` refers to Linux, not an emulator. To that end, if I run `flutter emulators`, I will be given the following output:

```
1 available emulator:

android34 • android34 •  • android

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
```

This emulator was created using the command `avdmanager create avd --name android34 --package "system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"` and was generated without incident. In fact, running `flutter emulators --launch android34` successfully launches the emulator in its own window, with full functionality. I have tested both running and not running the emulator with VS Code open, and in both cases, it fails to recognise it.

If it helps, my `.bashrc` file contains the following environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/:$PATH
```

**All of the above commands have been tested successfully in both VS Code and the virtual (bash) terminal**.

### Issue

Despite the emulator being successfully created and run, when I try to click `Create Android emulator` in VS Code, I am returned an error; namely,

```
avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK
```

This is evidently not true, given I have run `avdmanager`. So I am supposing something is awry in Flutter or Dart within VS Code.

Just as an additional aside, I had also successfully built my app into an apk via the command line. But going to `Terminal` -> `Run Build Task...` -> `flutter: build apk` within VS Code results in a (perhaps related) error:

```
[!] No Android SDK found. Try setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
```

I went back and edited `.bashrc` to include this, and ran `printenv` in the terminal within VS Code to verify it was there, which it was, but the processes still fail (building; which is not important, and adding an emulator).

Answer (score 0):

avdmanager should be in $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin, try this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android/sdk
PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but copying the above lines (and commenting out the lines already in `.bashrc`) did not yield a success, unfortunately.